# what are good blogs to read relating java, spring, hibernate, maven?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

To continue to question further I'm more interested in blogs, websites who once in a while release a tutorial, tip or best-practice on the topics I mentioned. For ex : 
http://net.tutsplus.com/ is very good website to follow if you wanna learn about or upgrade your knowledge about CSS, HTML, Javascript, PHP .. Is there a website like this for Java and related technologies?

Comment: Related: "Good sources to learn about Java trends" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539954/good-sources-to-learn-about-java-trends

Comment: @matt b This is not only about Java, its about these other technologies as well, so far I haven't found a website who updates regularly, and gives examples and best practices how to do certain things more efficiently or just quick tips. its really shame that such a website doesn't exist(or maybe it does) I'm still waiting for an answer

Comment: There are 8 links in the question I linked to about places to learn about "Java trends". I can't imagine that Hibernate and Spring and Maven would not fall under the umbrella of "Java trends".

Comment: @matt b yes matt that is true but that is not what I'm asking, I'm not asking about performance, technologies, I'm looking for daily uses, encountered problems, optimal solutions, best-practice tips and of course trends.

Comment: That is highly depending on your current skill set.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen What do you mean?

Comment: For a given blog to be good, it needs to be presenting and discussion things at your current skill level and interests.  You probably do not want to hear about "using static or *this*" or "there are some speed advantages when using the 64-bit version of Java on HP/UX".  That does not mean that others don't.  Hence "good blogs" depend on whether you are in the target audience.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen By good blogs I mean practical problems and examples how they are solved..

Comment: I've heard google is a pretty good search engine

Comment: BlueRaja The Green Unicorn I still use askjeeves.com , gee maybe thats why I couldn't find any, darn it I'll try this google you speak of

Answer (score 101, accepted):

I'll list some of the ones I'm reading, via RSS:

Blog aggregators:

- http://java.dzone.com
- http://javacodegeeks.com
- http://www.programcreek.com/2012/11/top-100-java-developers-blogs/

Blogs:

- http://relation.to/Bloggers/Gavin - Gavin King - the guy behind Hibernate, Seam, Weld, Ceylon
- http://vladmihalcea.com/ - Vlad Mihalcea's blog (Hibernate Developer Advocate)
- http://blog.springsource.com/ - Spring source team blog
- http://developers-blog.org/
- http://misko.hevery.com/ - Misko Hevery, on testability and tdd
- http://krams915.blogspot.in/
- http://programcreek.com/
- http://mkyong.com
- http://blog.jooq.org - On Java, SQL, and jOOQ (and occasionally Hibernate)
- [my blog](http://techblog.bozho.net)

Websites:

- A couple of JavaLobby forum sections - you can follow whichever section of [the forum](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/c5601.html) you like
- http://www.theserverside.com/ - The Server Side
- http://www.devx.com/Java/Door/6972 - DevX Java zone
- http://www.javaworld.com/ - JavaWorld
- http://www.infoq.com/java/ - InfoQ
- http://www.java.net/articles - java.net articles
- http://onjava.com/
- http://www.javased.com - Search Engine for Java Code Examples
- http://modernpathshala.com  - Java
- http://www.baeldung.com/  -Spring or Java

Comment: was the downvote due to giving a link to my blog?

Comment: http://www.programcreek.com Diagrams and Code to understand key concepts.

Comment: @Bozho I see no reason to hide your own blog. Revert, if you disagree.

Answer (score 9):

The basics:

#### Maven

- Sonatype Blog: http://www.sonatype.com/people/
- Brett Porter's blog: http://brettporter.wordpress.com/

#### Hibernate

- In relation to...: http://blog.hibernate.org/

#### Spring

- SpringSource Team Blog: http://blog.springsource.com/

Comment: The current Hibernate blog is http://in.relation.to

Answer (score 5):

You can read [Spring Articles](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/spring/1/) and [Hibernate Articles](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/hibernate/1/)

Answer (score 5):

[Mkyong.com](http://www.mkyong.com/)

[DZone](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/)

[Rose India](http://www.roseindia.net/)

[Ben McCann's blog](http://www.benmccann.com/blog/)

[Vlad Mihalcea's blog (Hibernate Developer Advocate)](http://vladmihalcea.com/)

Comment: mkyong.com is really a great one. Mostly because it comes out at the top of google search result. I suppose it did a great job in SEO as well

Comment: RoseIndia.net is the worst.

Answer (score 4):

Although it's not a blog, but [Java Posse Podcast](http://www.javaposse.com/) and its shownotes cover most trends in Java world. For a collection of Java tutorials and its related framework, [Good Tutorials](http://www.good-tutorials.com/tutorials/java)
is a site you want to spend your time with.

Comment: IMO, the signal to noise ratio is very low on that podcast. I used to love listening to the Java Posse podcast, but I realize now that they have a lot of fluff and irrelevant jabber.  I don't have time for fluff anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I will use this opportunity to point you to my modest Java blog:
http://eyalsch.wordpress.com/

I add a post about once a month, usually about non-trivial Java issues that I encounter.

Comment: Also I would like to point another blog here: http://devmain.blogspot.com